# Why does Jasmine not find my specs?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I set up the basic example (Chapter1) from Javascript Unit testing and it works, e.g.[image]

Why, when I set up a new directory for chapter 2 in what seems to be the same way but with my own spec do I get no specs being run:

[image]

My runner file has:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/SimpleMath.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="spec/SimpleMathSpec.js"></script>
```

My Spec file is

```
spec/SimpleMathSpec.js
```

and my source file is

```
src/SimpleMath.js
```

They both do exist:

```
$ ls src/SimpleMath.js 
src/SimpleMath.js
10:56:21 durrantm U2017 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/jasmine_2017/Chapter2 
$ ls spec/SimpleMathSpec.js 
spec/SimpleMathSpec.js
```

Network Tab shows them being found ok - though not sure why Zero size ???
[image]

I can even see that the file was loaded:
[image]

Contents:

```
spec/SimpleMathSpec.js:

describe("SimpleMath", function() {
  var simpleMath;

  beforeEach(function() {
    simpleMath = new SimpleMath();
  }); 

  it("should calculate a factorial for a positive number", function() {
    result=simpleMath.getFactorial(3);
    expect(result).toEqual(6);
  }); 

  it("should calculate a factorial for 0 - which will be zero", function() {
    result=simpleMath.getFactorial(0);
    expect(result).toEqual(0);
  }); 

  it("should calculate a factorial for -3 - which will raise an error", function() {
    result=simpleMath.getFactorial(-3);
    expect(result).toThrow Error;
  }); 

});

src/SimpleMath.js:

SimpleMath = function() {}; 
SimpleMath.prototype.getFactorial = function(number) {
  if (number < 0) {
    throw new Error("Can't be less than zero");
  }
  else if (number == 1 || number == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return number * this.getFactorial(number-1);
  }
}
SimpleMath.prototype.signum = function(number) {
  if (number > 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (number == 0) {
  return 0;
  } else {
    return -1; 
  }
}
SimpleMath.prototype.average = function(number1, number2) {
  return (number1 + number2) / 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the 0 B size is because the files are being loaded locally (i.e., `file://`), so there's no network activity. There is what I think is a typo in your test file: `expect(result).toThrow Error;` should be `expect(result).toThrowError();`. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes that was it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax error:

```
expect(result).toThrow Error;
```

should be

```
expect(result).toThrowError;
```

Syntax errors show in the web inspect tools console and prevent any specs from running.